# Prove that any normal matrix is the sum of hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi I was wondering if this is true. Let $M_{n}[\mathbb{C}]$ be matrices with complex values. Then any normal matrix is the sum of a hermitian matrix and another hermitian matrix multiplied by $i$. and these two matrices commute. But I do not know a proof.

Comment: Start with the conclusion. $A = X + iY$ then $A^* = X^* - i Y^* = X - iY$. Now solve for $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: normal matrices are unitarily diagonalisable.